# Custom Fields as Post Type Options

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-field, hooks, options

Im using a theme for vehicle listings and the WPUF Pro plugin for frontend submitting.

WPUF plugin automatically reads the taxonomies of themes post_type (vehicle), but the theme got vehicle (details) options, that plugin cannot handle on save.

I tried to use the hook that weDevs provide in documentation, but no success (and no respond on tickets too).

On Screen Options I can enable the WPUF Custom Field and see the options that I submit on form, but i want to save them as vehicle options (same as I submit a vehicle as admin through dashboard).

`theme/function.php`

```
function wpuf_update_vehicle_year( $post_id ) {
    $year = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'seek_property_year', true );

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'seek_property_year', $year );
}

add_action( 'wpuf_add_post_after_insert', 'wpuf_update_vehicle_year' );
```

Any suggestion on how i can pass the custom fields of WPUF to themes post_type options ?

Comment: If you are trying to use a function that weDev supply you with and that does not work, I would contact them because you do pay for a service...

Comment: Useless forum, unanswered tickets...That was the first thing i did as a customer.

Comment: Ok. How is the themes post_type_options stored?

Comment: According to ThemeFuse,there is triggered the save_post action, and the framework seek extension is attached to that action, it selects automatically the options and syncs them with the aditional database table used by seek extensions to store the vehicle options for search.

Comment: I don't know what code you've written, but one major thing is that it doesn't rely on global $post...  look here for more info... https://wedevs.com/support/topic/code-to-execute-in-save_post-action-not-work/      hope it helps...

Comment: The code is in the question

Comment: Ok. What actually happens then?  Does the function execute at all?

Comment: I'm not getting any result, error or needed value. I'll check another code until they answer. It doesnt seem that is executed

Answer (score 0):

Your code...

```
function wpuf_update_vehicle_year( $post_id ) {
    $year = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'seek_property_year', true );

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'seek_property_year', $year );
}

add_action( 'wpuf_add_post_after_insert', 'wpuf_update_vehicle_year' );
```

is ***probably*** executed, but nothing will change anyway because the thing it does is to grab meta data (with `get_post_meta`) for seek_property_year and then update the same meta data with the same value:

1. Get value for `$post_id` for seek_property_year. Lets say the value is 2010
2. Put value for `$post_id` for seek_property_year. Put 2010 into seek_property_year
3. ...will result in no changes in database (nothing seems to happen)

Comment: Issue is resolved by ThemeFuse support.